# getting error connecting to fireabse-admin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

trying to connect to fireabse using admin access and the config that was provided by firebase, it is throwing error that i added in the question it seems library is throwing error.

firebase.js

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const firebaseConfig = {
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
module.exports = app;
```

controller.js

```
import app from '../../firebase';

const db = app.firestore();
const addUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    console.log("Adding new user");
    const data = req.body;
    await db.collection("Users").doc().set(data);
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Record saved successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

module.exports = {
addUser
};

Error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js 84:65
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (84:65)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|         // use the native Promise and then remove this.
|         this.Promise = Promise;
>         this.INTERNAL = new FirebaseNamespaceInternals(appStore ?? new lifecycle_1.AppStore());
```

Answer (score 0):

For `"firebase": "^9.18.0"` and `"firebase-admin": "^11.5.0"` try modular import with classic `require` keyword:

```
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');

const firebaseConfig = {/*..*/};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

module.exports = app;
```

and

```
const app = require("../../firebase");
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

const db = getFirestore(app);
```

It is possible to set up TypeScript code with `import` keyword for functions. Though it is not an easy task, Firebase does not properly support TypeScript out of the box now.

Comment: thanks for the response getting below error now `ERROR in ./firebase.js 1:38
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:38)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> const admin = require("firebase-admin";
| // import {
| //   getFirestore,
 @ ./controllers/users/userController.js 1:12-37
 @ ./server.js`

Comment: Firebase definitely supports TypeScript just fine.  It even has [type bindings](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/src/firebase-namespace-api.ts) for all of its JavaScript SDKs, both admin and web client.  It also supports import syntax, as you can see from the [README on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node).

Comment: Thank you @DougStevenson for the TS project reference. I will look closely at it. When I built a custom TypeScript functions project there were so many problems: it required bundling to one index.js file, problems with referencing cross package from mono-repo, including custom setup for transpilation and bundling, installation of NPM packages in Firebase only supports public refs in package.json , as some others issues. Your example is again a custom TS project with some settings. What I mean by proper support out of the box is to have a command: `firebase init --typescript`.

Comment: @DougStevenson Not to mention that Functions have a lot of problems with `tsc  --watch` recompiling mode, it is often required to stop enulators, re-build functions TS source code, and start emulators again. Far from ideal support like it is done, for example, in Next.JS. @hussain Sorry for stepping out of the topic.

Comment: @hussain Can you please share your FIrebase NPM package versions. And the path where you have the above files, something like `/root/functions/...`.

Comment: here are the versions     "firebase": "^9.18.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0"